# strings in c automatically concatenates

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, linked-list

```
struct flight_list{
    char fcode[4];
    string20 srccity;
    string20 descity;
    int deptime;
    int duration;

};   

 void add_flight(string20 city[], struct flight_list flight_arr[]){
        int i,j;
        int check;
        char flight[MAX];
        string20 src;
        string20 choice;
        system("cls");
        do{
        while(strcmp(flight_arr[i].fcode,"")!=0)
        i++;
        do{
        check = 0;
        printf("flight code: ");
        scanf("%s",flight);
        flight[4] = '\0';
        strcpy(flight_arr[i].fcode,flight);

        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(strcmp(flight_arr[j].fcode,flight_arr[i].fcode)==0){
                printf("not unique\n");
                getch();
                system("cls");  
                check = 1;  
            }

        }

        }while(check == 1);
        printf("source city: ");
        scanf("%s",src);
        strcpy(flight_arr[i].srccity,src);
        printf("%s",flight_arr[i].fcode);


        }while(strcmp(flight,"no")!=0);
    }
```

the flight_arr[].fcode concatenates with the srccity I don't know why all the values of the structure array was initialized before going to this function and in this function no other function was used to concatenate any strings please help!

Comment: What is `string20`? What is `MAX`?

Comment: By the way you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code: Remember that local variables are not initialized, and using them uninitialized leads to undefined behavior. You never initialize the index variable `i`.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct flight_list{
    char fcode[4];
```

---

```
        scanf("%s",flight);
        flight[4] = '\0';
        strcpy(flight_arr[i].fcode,flight);
```

No! `flight_arr[i].fcode` has space for 4 characters; `flight[4]` is a 5th chracter.

Comment: it has to be only 4 characters :) that's why i put null on the 5th character this doesn't solve any problem sorry

Comment: problem is that "ABCD" does not fit into `flight_arr[i].fcode`. You need space for the string terminator.

Comment: @PNC It's four character *plus terminator* so your arrays must be five characters big. If they only contain space for four characters and you write to the fifth, where would that fifth character end up?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't understand PMG's answer. He's right. You can't get access to `flight[4]` if you declared it `char fcode[4];` as it will have spots only from 0 to 3. There is NO 5th spot. You're actually sliding to a memory different than the one you meant. In C, strings should be declared to the size of string contained+1 (NULL). So if I want to create a string which will contain "Hello" (Hello is 5 letters by itself) and I would declare it this way:

```
char mystr[] = "Hello";
```

then the size would be determined by the literal string input - which is SIX and NOT FIVE as it takes another  room for NULL.
By the way - `scanf("%s")` automatically ends the string input with NULL - as `gets` does - but I would recommend `fgets()` which is used this way `fgets(StringInput, StringSize, stdin);` and in your case `fgets(flight, 4, stdin);` and that's it.